# Dragging in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

How can I drag and drop an image into a div by using Ext JS? I also want to drag my image inside the div. I am aware there is "draggable" property in Ext JS, but I can not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/dd/dragdropzones.html)! It is example of a custom d&d using Extjs4 framework, take a look at the source code!